# Get all after character in Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need button that will seperate words from left and right of `:` character. I know how to get all before `:`, but how could I get all after `:`?

My code:

```
TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim findtext2 As String = "(.*?)(?=:)" 'Gets all before ":"
Dim myregex2 As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim doregex2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2)
Dim matches2 As String = ""
For Each match2 As Match In doregex2
    matches2 = matches2 + match2.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
MsgBox(matches2)
```

I tried following with `Dim findtext2 As String = "(?=:)(.*?)"`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The regex would be `(?<=:).*`, but @Rion has the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, that works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your string would contain a colon, you could use a [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) call instead of a regular expression to get the sections you need :

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains(":") Then
    ' Split using the colon '
    Dim sections = TextBox1.Text.Split(":")
    ' Get the first part '
    Dim before = sections(0)
    ' Get the second part '
    Dim after = sections(1)
End If
```

Comment: Yeah, works with simple lists (as book:pencil). I've tried this with email list (example@domain.com:password) and it will get "password", but also email on next line (without its password). Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to consider using the `File.ReadAllLines()` method if you plan on the content on each line being independent of one another. You could then simply iterate through each line and grab your contents, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Yeah, i think that would work, but it's much simplier (at least for me) with regex `(?<=:).*`. Thank you for idea!